# Sequelize Include On Through association

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

Is It possible in sequelize to include on through association..
i have tried like this shown code but it returns error...

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined**

i m using sql dialect

```
let instructorGrade = await model.Instructor.findOne({
                where: { id },
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: model.SchoolGrade,
                        as: 'instructorSchoolGrades',
                        through: {
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: model.Grade,
                                    as: 'schoolGrades'
                                },
                                {
                                    model: model.Section,
                                    as: 'schoolGradeSection'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Here is the github issue which is same as mine but i havent find any solution
[1]: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [**Nested eager loading**](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/models-usage/index.html#nested-eager-loading). So for example, you query might be something like:

```
let instructorGrade = await model.Instructor.findOne({
    where: { id },
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: [
        {
            model: model.SchoolGrade,
            as: 'instructorSchoolGrades',
            include: [
                {
                    model: model.Grade,
                    as: 'schoolGrades'
                },
                {
                    model: model.Section,
                    as: 'schoolGradeSection'
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
});
```